# linux machine start but stuck before startup completed and no ssh access

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel, kernel

we have linux rhel 7.2 server

we we boot the machine we see that machine stuck on that screen

[image]

any advice why linux not start up?

this screen what we get after some time

[image]

Comment: What happens after the timeout?

Comment: see the update I share screen

Comment: Ok, did you follow the advice (`systemctl status rhnsd.service`) ?

Comment: we dont have ssh access , so how to do it without ssh access?

Comment: You mean that *you* have no SSH access or do you mean that SSH ist not available in general? AFAIK the failed start of the rhnsd service should not affect hte start of the SSH daemon. If someone has access to this server you have to update the rhnsd daemon or disable it as a workaround to prevent this error on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says:

> **A start job is running for LSB ( 3 out of 5 min ).**

It requires 5 minutes to finish. After that,  your machine will continue booting.

Did you wait the job run time to finish ?
Do you have still problem after job finished?

Comment: see my update in the question